# Grails gsp pagination not breaks list item

Tags: grails, pagination

Today when i customize list method of my controller,facing issue in list.gsp page.My problem is that all records  are displayed on a single page.
for ex. Suppose i have 15 records then all 15 will show  on first page and also there in next link at footer.when clicks on it all pages show same 15 records.

I was customize code because i need to run query and basis of result of query show records on list page.

```
def query = "from Book where isAvailable = 'true'"
        def bookInstanceList = Book.findAll(query)
        [bookInstanceList: bookInstanceList , bookInstanceTotal: bookInstanceList.size()]
```

it shows all records on a single page and records are not paginate on different page.
i want to show maximum 10 records on each page.

please reply me where i am missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So pagination will not work that way. You are getting your total of the resulting number of rows that were returned, not what would have been returned without pagination.

```
def bookQuery = Book.where{ isAvailable == 'true' }
[bookInstanceList: bookQuery.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: bookQuery.count()]
```

`params` should contain `max` and `offset` to implement pagination.

Comment: @ James Kleeh  - thanks for reply.what will be the value of max and offset- i have passed max=10 and offset=0.Currently i have 15 records in database.it shows 10 records on first page,and shows   option for move to next page but when i clicks on next nothing happens.

Comment: it gives output as my requirement but pagination not working.

Comment: When i click on next  url is updated to -http://localhost:8080/myApp/book/list?offset=10&max=10 but it shows same record and stay on same page.